# Raspberry Pi - SSH forbidden

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I've been using MySQL Workbench to add a few databases to my raspberry. However, when I turned it on and on again, it wouldn't let me allow logging in again.

```
bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
/bin/_kssh.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygssp-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what to do with this error; everything worked fine for the last few months. How can I get rid of this issue so I can SSH into my Raspberry Pi again? I have a SD-card reader at my disposal to use if any edits are neccesary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed by using an other SSH client. My current software wasn't able to connect anymore. Changing SSH client when you encounter such error should solve the problem.

Comment: Mad props for coming back a week later and posting the solution.